# When I use an array inside a struct, I encounter some strange thing

Tags: arrays, c, struct

When I run the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

struct BC_messages {
    uint16_t hz;
    uint16_t counter;
    uint16_t data[];
};

struct BC_messages* createMessage(struct BC_messages* m, uint16_t hz, 
                                    uint16_t counter, int a)
{
    m = malloc(sizeof(*m) + sizeof(uint16_t) * a);
    m->hz = hz;
    m->counter = counter;
    
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    struct BC_messages* m1 = createMessage(m1, 2, 4, 6);
    m1->data[7] = 0xCCCC;
    printf("%d" , m1->data[7]);

    return 0;
}
```

Why can I access `m1->data[7]` when the array length is 6?
I can even access `m1->data[1234]`, what is happening?

I was expecting not able to access the array when the array is out of range.

Comment: C have no bounds-checking. It's up to you as the programmer to make sure you don't go out of bounds of the memory you allocate.

Comment: There is no bounds checking in C. You just access the memory that is there. It's _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: Also note that while the compiler might be able to catch it for an actual array (that haven't decayed to a pointer) it's not possible for flexible array members or variable-length arrays, because these arrays don't have a size at compile-time.

Comment: @施凱翔 "I was expecting not able to access the array when the array is out of range." --> OK.  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Haha, I was expect to get an error.

Comment: You only get an error if it damages something. It's an error to drop a dinner plate but it does not always break.

Comment: @施凱翔, C does not certainly emit code with the error checking needed to "get an error".  That is why it is fast and small.  It assumes you are not doing foolish things.  If you need the program to do many checks, consider other languages.